# HTML Navigation menu bar refusing to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this segment of code which is due for part of my assignment, the aim is to make a functional index page, but I have written this code but cannot find at what point the Menu key refuses to activate the dropdown list. I've tried it on Chrome/Firefox and have issues with both but I cannot find exactly where it is breaking.

Guidance would be much appreciated.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Desserts</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drinks</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: You should provide jsfiddle example with all the required js and css files, otherwise there is no way for us to reproduce the problrm

Comment: Be sure you've added all necessary scripts/files

Comment: Seeing as this is a Bootstrap navbar, and you didn't use the bootstrap tag in the question, I'm assuming that you perhaps used this code from the bootstrap website without really knowing what bootstrap is? In order for it to work you would need to download the bootstrap CSS/JS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have included all of Bootstrap's javascript files :

```
    <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Something so simple! I knew it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add the external files. Details are in the Snippet

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* Changes
line 1
|| Added external link to Bootstrap.css file
=======================
line 47
|| Added external jQuery script file
=======================
line 49
|| Added external Bootstrap.js script file
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Desserts</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drinks</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bad idea to include css file in html body